# Swift sqlite How to run multiple queries (inserts, updates, etc) in one string

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am using the sqlite3 library in swift, trying to run multiple insert statements separated by semi colon, like this:

```
INSERT INTO PARAMS VALUES ('t1', 'r1');INSERT INTO PARAMS VALUES ('t2', 'r2');...;...;
```

The code I currently have is:

```
let multiQueries= "INSERT INTO PARAMS VALUES ('t1', 'r1');INSERT INTO PARAMS VALUES ('t2', 'r2');"
var queryStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
if sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbPointer, multiQueries, -1, &queryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
    if sqlite3_step(queryStatement) != SQLITE_DONE {
        print("Cannot execute query")
    }else{
        print("ok")
    }
} else {
    print("Queries could not be prepared")
}
```

But only the first query is executed. I tried to do multiple sqlite3_step like doing a select statement, but the second time I call it, it returns error code 21.

Comment: You need `sqlite3_exec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer, credits for @rmaddy for the hint. The following code works fine for me.

```
var errMsg: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>? = nil
if sqlite3_exec(dbPointer, multiQueries, nil, nil, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK {
    print("Cannot execute query")
    if let errMsg = errMsg {
        print(String(cString: errMsg))
    }
}else{
    print("ok")
}
```

From sqlite documents, sqlite3_step is for queries with results like selects, and sqlite3_exec is for queries with no results like inserts.

Comment: sqlite3_step is just fine for inserts. You need to use `sqlite3_exec` if the string has multiple statements.